# Setting basic auth in microprofile rest client

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I have a service which exposes a number of Jax-RS interfaces for its services. I now want to use those interfaces to connect with the services. I am using Quarkus, which means I am using the microprofile rest client. Because I already have the JaxRS interface, using the @RegisterRestClient method is not really viable. Instead I am using the RestClientBuilder.

```
    MyService client = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .baseUri(URI.create("https://localhost:8080"))
        .build(MyService.class);
```

The problem I am running into is authentication. The services i need to reach are locked behind basic Auth. All the guides I have found for the microprofile REST client are variations of [this](https://itnext.io/authentication-with-microprofile-rest-client-d1e9da774f70) where the solution is to add a headerparam. This is not possible however, because I already have the interface premade, and copy-pasting the entire thing to add a header parameter is really something i would rather avoid.

It should also be mentioned that i have tried a @Provider filter to set the headers, but I can't seem to figure out how to only target a single REST client using that method, and I have several.

So: How do i set up basic authentication without messing with the Jax-Rs interface itself, using the microprofile rest client?

Comment: I *think* you can add your provider to that client only by registering it manually. The `RestClientBuilder` implements `Configurable`, you can use an appropriate `register` method. On the other hand, authentication through HTTP headers *IS* a part of your contract, just like query params would be. I think it would be appropriate to add this annotation to the original JAX-RS interface, if you have access to modify it.

Answer (score 8):

**UPDATE**

Starting from Quarkus 3.9, you will be able to do:

```java
@Path("/my")
@ClientBasicAuth(username = "${service.username}", password = "${service.password}")
public interface MyService {

  
}
```

where `service.username` and `service.password` are configuration properties that must be set at runtime to the username and password that allow access to the service being called.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You should be able to use the `@ClientHeaderParam` annotation on `MyService`.
Something like:

```java
@Path("/my")
@ClientHeaderParam(name = "Authorization", value = "{lookupAuth}")
public interface MyService {

  default String lookupAuth() {
    return "Basic " + 
         Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("someuser:somepass".getBytes());
  }
}
```

See [this](https://itnext.io/authentication-with-microprofile-rest-client-d1e9da774f70) for more details

If modifying the interface is not possible, you have two options:

- Create an interface that extends the one you use with this annotation:

```java
@ClientHeaderParam(name = "Authorization", value = "{lookupAuth}")
public interface MyServiceWrapper extends MyService {
  default String lookupAuth() {
    return "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("someuser:somepass".getBytes());
  }
}
```

- Create a `ClientRequestFilter` that fills the `Authorization` header:

```java
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class BasicRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        requestContext.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, getAccessToken());
    }

    private String getAccessToken() {
        return "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("someuser:somepass".getBytes());
    }
}
```

And register the filter, e.g. programmatically:

```java
MyService client = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
    .register(BasicRequestFilter.class)
    .baseUri(URI.create("https://localhost:8080"))
    .build(MyService.class);
```

Comment: The problem is that, as i wrote in the question, I can't change the service interface. That's kind of the whole point.

Comment: I'll edit the answer to address this specifically.

Comment: This is too much of extra code, why dint they just provided a method to add headers

Comment: @Derrick you are right! We rectified that situation for Quarkus 3.9

Answer (score 1):

You can register a per-instance `org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.BasicAuthentication` (or you can write a similar component) and register it using RestClientBuilder.